# smarty if empty else smarty value

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

I have smarty value if it empty need another result

```
{get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'}
```

This value print "test" If this value is empty else how can I use?

```
 {if !empty({get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'})} 
  No value
 {else}
 {get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'}
{/if}
```

This code not work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [the `{capture}` function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl) to capture the output into a variable, then choose what to do with it:

```
{capture name="video_meta"}{get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'}{/capture}
{if empty($smarty.capture.video_meta)}
 No value
 {else}
 {$smarty.capture.video_meta}
{/if}
```

Comment: At first I thought the same, but then decide that no reason call plugin if empty variable $video_data.id...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak I interpreted the question as meaning that the *result* of the function was sometimes empty, not that the *input* was empty. So that the test is not "do we have a video ID?" but "do we have metadata item 'foo' for this video ID?"

Answer (score 3):

You can assign value to variable:

```
{if empty($code)}
    {assign var='code' value='404'}
{/if}
```

but i suppose that you need something like:

```
{if empty($video_data.id)}
    No value
{else}
    {get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'}
{/if}
```

because `get_video_meta` - it's smarty plugin, and you can't use it like you try to use...

In foreach:

```
{foreach from=$video_data key=k item=v}
    {if empty($k)}
        No value
    {else}
        {get_video_meta video_id=$v.id key=$k}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: What you mean key value? Do you use foreach?

Comment: Where i need add "test"? this code will display "test" it is in tpl {get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'}